# Python collections.Mapping: Uses of dict_keys that __iter__ and __contains__ don't already serve

Tags: python, python-collections

In python 3, a dict (or anything implementing the collections.Mapping interface) has a `keys()` method that returns a `dict_keys`, which is iterable (yielding keys, as `__iter__()` does) but can also respond to `key in dict_keys` in `O(1)` time (as `__contains__` does).

But what else can `dict_keys` do for me that `__iter__` and `__contains__` doesn't already?

Comment: It can identify your object as a mapping. That's how dicts are duck typed in CPython. It could be done in other ways though, so that doesn't really justify it's existence.

Comment: It acts like a set in a few ways that dict doesn’t, so you can do `d.keys() & {"foo", "bar"}`, for example. I suppose you also get a guarantee that stuff you pass it to can’t modify your dict.

Comment: It is a set-like view over the dictionaries keys.